# Get value from optional chaining from generated code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have created a React app that uses [graphql-code-generator](http://graphql-code-generator.) to generate query function.
The generated types look as follows:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import * as Apollo from '@apollo/client';
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type Exact<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
export type MakeOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]?: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };
export type MakeMaybe<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
};

export type Query = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  skills?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Skills>>>;
};

export type Skills = {
  __typename?: 'Skills';
  id: Scalars['Int'];
  description: Scalars['String'];
};

export type GetSkillsQueryVariables = Exact<{ [key: string]: never; }>;


export type GetSkillsQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { skills?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'Skills' }
    & Pick<Skills, 'id' | 'description'>
  )>>> }
);


export const GetSkillsDocument = gql`
    query getSkills {
  skills {
    id
    description
  }
}
    `;

/**
 * __useGetSkillsQuery__
 *
 * To run a query within a React component, call `useGetSkillsQuery` and pass it any options that fit your needs.
 * When your component renders, `useGetSkillsQuery` returns an object from Apollo Client that contains loading, error, and data properties
 * you can use to render your UI.
 *
 * @param baseOptions options that will be passed into the query, supported options are listed on: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#options;
 *
 * @example
 * const { data, loading, error } = useGetSkillsQuery({
 *   variables: {
 *   },
 * });
 */
export function useGetSkillsQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.QueryHookOptions<GetSkillsQuery, GetSkillsQueryVariables>) {
        return Apollo.useQuery<GetSkillsQuery, GetSkillsQueryVariables>(GetSkillsDocument, baseOptions);
      }
export function useGetSkillsLazyQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.LazyQueryHookOptions<GetSkillsQuery, GetSkillsQueryVariables>) {
          return Apollo.useLazyQuery<GetSkillsQuery, GetSkillsQueryVariables>(GetSkillsDocument, baseOptions);
        }
export type GetSkillsQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useGetSkillsQuery>;
export type GetSkillsLazyQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useGetSkillsLazyQuery>;
export type GetSkillsQueryResult = Apollo.QueryResult<GetSkillsQuery, GetSkillsQueryVariables>;
```

In a React component, I use the generated query hook as follows:

```
interface NewIdeaProps {
    errorHandler<T>(ae: ApolloError): T
}

export default function NewIdea({errorHandler}: NewIdeaProps) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const {loading, error, data} = useGetSkillsQuery();

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div className={classes.loading}>
                <CircularProgress/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (error) {
        return (
            <div>
                {errorHandler(error)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Paper elevation={2} className={classes.container}>
            .....
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="new-idea-tags"
                options={data?.skills}
                disableCloseOnSelect
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.description}
                renderOption={(option, {selected}) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Checkbox
                            icon={icon}
                            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                            style={{marginRight: 8}}
                            checked={selected}
                        />
                        {option.description}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
                fullWidth
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Skills"/>
                )}
            />

        </Paper>
    )


}
```

It compiles and runs as expected, but the compiler shows the following error message:
[image]

Why `options={data?.skills}` does not get accepted? What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Sorry I forgot to post schema definition:

```
type Query {
    skills: [Skills]
}

type Skills {
    id: Int!,
    description: String!
}
```

Comment: source gql types? skills array elements nullable ?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: try `skills: [Skills!]`, compare/show error messages if still exists

Comment: What should I write to use the data? I have tried `options={data?.skills?}`, but the expression is missing.